# laravel api result datatypes changed when the hosting changed

Tags: php, host

I transferred my laravel api from a host to another ...
the json result was like this in the first host(PHP Version 7.0.25)
shows integer values as strings

```
        "items": [
            {
                "category_id": "4",
                "price": "20",
                "is_special_offer": "1",
                "status": "1",
```

and in the other host (PHP Version 7.1.8) I found it like this
shows integer values as integes

```
        "items": [
            {
                "category_id": 4,
                "price": 20,
                "is_special_offer": 1,
                "status": 1,
```

this is the code

```
 public function getAllCategories(){
    $info = Categories::with([ 'items' => function($q){
        $q->with(['item_services' => function($qq){
            $qq->with( ['service' => function($qqq){
                $qqq->select(
                    'id',
                    'name',
                    'image',
                    'status'
                );
            }]);
        }])->select(
            'id',
            'category_id',
            'name',
            'image',
            'price',
            'new_price',
            'discount',
            'discount_description',
            'is_special_offer',
            'has_merzam',
            'has_taneem',
            'neela',
            'nasha',
            'status');
    }])->select('id', 'name', 'image', 'status')->get();
    return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => trans('messages.success_message'), 'errors' => [], 'data' => $info]);
}
```

How could I fix this issue ?

Comment: Please share your code also ?

Comment: http://divvat.com/code.JPG

Comment: share your code as a text in your question not image

Comment: I updated the question